# Linq query to return list within a list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Hi I have following two model classes

```
public class c1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int ptId { get; set; }
    public int bId { get; set; }
    public int rId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<styles> newStruct { get; set; }
}

public class styles
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int bId { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to write a linq query

```
var records = (from y in db.main
               join c in db.secondary on y.bId equals c.bId
               where c.id == id
               select new c1
               {
                   pId= c.pId,
                   id = c.id,
                   newStruct = new List<styles>
                   {
                       new styles
                       {
                           id=y.room_id,
                           desc=y.desc,
                       }
                   }
               });

return records.ToList();
```

Problem I am having is that in newStruct is suppose to be List of all the styles but it just returns one style at a time rather than one list. 
Please let me know how can it return record where inside it contains list of styles 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a sublist by main list, you should use `group by`,

You can try this, but I'm not sure it worked. Becasue I couldn't compile it.

```
var records = (from y in db.main
                           join c in db.secondary on y.bId equals c.bId
                           where c.id == id
                           group c by new
                           {
                               c.pId,
                               c.id
                           } into gcs
                           select new c1
                           {
                               pId = c.Key.pId,
                               id = c.Key.id,
                               newStruct = from g in gcs select new styles { id=g.room_id, desc=g.desc}
                           });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this LINQ to Entities?  If so, and the mappings are correct in the edmx, you can try:

```
var records = 
    from c in db.secondary
    where c.id == id
    select new c1
    {
        pId = c.pId,
        id = c.id,
        newStruct = c.main.Select(m => new styles { id = m.room_id, desc = m.desc })
    };

return records.ToList();
```